# Jquery call from php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page which has multiple links and I want to execute the Jquery function when a link is clicked. I want to send the value attached with link. Unfortunately, my Jquery function doesn't get executed.

Here is a snippet of code from php file.

```
  foreach ($ties as $tie) {
      echo "<a href='#' id ='species'><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";
  }
```

And in my jquery run method, the code snippet looks like this:

```
 $("#species").click(function(){
      alert("Hi");
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you cannot use the same id for more lines, switch to class (even in the listener onlick function)

Comment: same id in foreach loop  ???

Comment: @Vicky that's wrong, if you set the id dynamic you'll have to add a listener for each id. Instead work with class to avoid doing that

Comment: $('.species').click(function(){
        alert("Hi");

    echo "<a href='#' class ='species'><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";

Comment: Thank you @Goikiu . Still it's not showing that dialog alert for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello as mentioned before you shouldn't use id's in a loop since id's should be unique in the context of the whole page. You should be using classes instead.

```
foreach ($ties as $tie) {
    echo "<a class="species" href="somepage.php?tie=$tie"><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";
}

$(".species").click(function() {
    // This is the clicked anchor.
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

You could also use html5 data attributes to store for instance tie id's. For future reference.

```
foreach ($ties as $tie) {
    echo "<a class="species" href="#" data-tie="$tieID"><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";
}

$(".species").click(function() {
    // This is the clicked anchor.
    console.log($(this).data("tie"));
});
```